# Do I need to provide xxhdpi images on Android?

Tags: android, image, dpi

I am developing an app which have a home screen consist of many icons. I see there are new `1080p phones (HTC Droid DNA)` which can have a density `up to 440`, do I need to make a `xxhdpi` version of the icons on the home screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should focus on the most popular screen densities, which is hdpi and xhdpi, see this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) for the distribution of each density.

And even you want to adapt to other density, you do not need to provide all drawables for these density. Android will scale them to proper size, but since the algorithm of android system for scale must be very fast, some drawables may lose quality after scale, you can specially provide these drawables for different densities. Drawable with texture may lose quality easily.